# How to make the same result like MATLAB code in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy-ndarray

This is MATLAB code

[image]

How to make python code with the same result like code in the picture if X in python is `np.array`?

Comment: There is no matlab code...

Comment: sorry, i just learn how to add image in the question. I already added image of MATLAB code in my question.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: Code is text. Stackoverflow is text. Why would you share the code as an image?! Please share code always as text

Answer (score 1):

For instance you could do:

```py
x = np.array([2, 3, 4])
x > 2

>>> array([False,  True,  True])
```

If you need integers instead of booleans, then do:

```py
y = x > 2
y.astype(int)
>>> array([0, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is almost exactly the same as in matlab except with a few numpy calls.

Create the array:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Y = X > 2
X[Y]
```

You could shorten it that way:

```py
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Y = X[X > 2]
```